# how to know a page become Dirty page in unix

Tags: unix, operating-system

i am having a function name "set page dirty" which is inside calling `__set_page_dirty_nobuffers(struct page *page)`. "`set page dirty`" is called by another *function*. i want to debug these function.i need a command which can hit my target function and to know that that page has dirtied.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty pages are pages that are intended to be written to harddisk but not yet written. Make small writes to HDD and see if it hits the function you are pointing to.